# Please Review : Prove that for a subgroup $N$ of $G$, $(\forall g \in G): \ gNg^{-1}=N \implies (\forall g \in G): \ gN=Ng$ (and one more)

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Prove for a subgroup $N$ of $G$, $$(\forall g \in G): \ gNg^{-1}=N
>  \implies (\forall g \in G): \ gN=Ng$$ and $$(\forall g \in G): \ gN
>  \subseteq Ng\implies (\forall g \in G): \ gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$$

---

**Proof 1:** Assume $\forall g \in G$ that $gNg^{-1}=N$. Let $n \in N$. Then $\forall g \in G$ and $n,n' \in N$ we have
$$n=gn'g^{-1} \implies ng=gn'$$
therefore $gN=Ng$.

---

**Proof 2:** Assume $\forall g \in G$ that $gN \subseteq Ng$. Let $n,n' \in N$. We then have
$$gn=n'g \implies gng^{-1}=n'$$
therefore $gNg^{-1} = N$, thus 
$$gNg^{-1} \subseteq N \text{ and } gNg^{-1} \supseteq N$$
and the first of which is our conclusion, ending the proof.

---

My main worry regarding these proofs is that I feel like the implications I made in the end seem like too large of steps. In the first proof, is it valid to say $ng = gn' \implies gN=Ng$? I'm tempted to say instead it would imply something like $Ng \subseteq gN$ since I'm aiming to show two sets are equal..

Similarly, in the second proof, I'm tempted to say something weaker than $gNg^{-1}=N$, it just feels like taking too large of a step.

Comment: In the first proof, $ng = gn'$ implies $ng \in gN$. Since this holds for any $n \in N$, it follows that $Ng \subseteq gN$. You can prove the reverse containment quite similarly.

Comment: Also, "$\forall g \in G$ and $n,n' \in N$" isn't right. Start with the hypothesis that $\forall g \in G$, we have $gNg^{-1} = N$. This means that given $g \in G$ and $n \in N$, **there exists** $n' \in N$ such that $gn'g^{-1} = n$. (You can't choose both $n$ and $n'$ arbitrarily for a given $g$.)

Comment: Use the fact that if $X$ is a group and $x \in X$, then $xX=X=Xx$. This can be seen by the fact that if $y \in X$, then $x(x^{-1}y)=y=(yx^{-1})x$. Hence if $ng=gn'$, then $Nng=Ng=gn'N=gN$.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you for the help! And I'll do what you mentioned about the hypothesis and try to take better care in the future!

Comment: @NickyHekster Oh I never thought about approaching it that way -- thank you!